# The Interesting Army

Tags: riddle

One day I was exploring the world of puzzling and stumbled across an interesting army. Each of the lead generals were followed by exactly three soldiers. All of the other generals were trailed by five soldiers each.

Using general knowledge only, who are the generals and who are the soldiers?

---

*(attribution: I found this by myself, but a google search reveals it's been found before, but I didn't see it on PSE, and feel it seems interesting enough to post)*

Comment: That's rot13(n phgr bofreingvba! V unqa'g abgvprq vg orsber).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here

> the army is the alphabet, the generals are the vowels, and the soldiers are the consonants. (For this purpose, Y is a consonant.)

Thus:

> a | b c d
>  e | f g h
>  i | j k l m n
>  o | p q r s t
>  u | v w x y z

Comment: The OP said to solve the puzzle "using general knowledge only". It seems to me that you used soldier knowledge also.

Comment: @msh210 I had to read your comment a few times to get it. Good one 

Comment: I am always disappointed when "general knowledge" quizzes aren't like "1. Give an example of a case where the adjective follows the noun in English. 2. Who was the 34th president of the United States? 3. Only one of the original 12 Dow Jones companies still exists under the same name as when the Dow Jones average began. Which one? ..."

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan One answer to your 1., is it rot13(Nggbearl Trareny)?

Comment: Yup. (Or Surgeon, or Director, or Secretary.)

Comment: It may seem obvious, but this only works with rot13(yngva nycunorg), not with any type. While I understand that this is the question's intention, I think it would be worth it to include this qualifier in the answer.

Comment: I think that when someone rot13(jevgvat va Ratyvfu) refers to rot13("gur nycunorg") without further qualification it isn't ambiguous what they mean.

Comment: rot13(VZB vg'f abg fb zhpu "jevgvat va Ratyvfu" nf orvat ernq ol n zbab-yvathny crefba va Ratyvfu), but alright, I raised a point you disagreed, let's move on.